# Story of alien, lives by touching people as they die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

He takes their bodies as his last one wears out.  As the story goes on he feels anxious.  He's not sure, he might be the only alien of his kind left on earth.  He begins to feel divided somehow. Then, a major duel with someone who knows what he is.  He wins the duel -- but as the story ends he realizes that everyone he's ever taken over is still inside his mind.  Including this last, very strong, adversary.  I loved this story and wish I could read it again.  Read it in the mid-90s but think it could have been 80s or earlier ... and for some reason I remember the final adversary as being -- a jesuit?  or some sort of very strong priest-person? Thanks for help!